# Preventing a click function in a jquery lightbox

Tags: jquery, click, prettyphoto

I am using [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/) lightbox and I'm trying to prevent the lightbox from opening unless an image has a class "active". It is being used in the [Contentflow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) script which adds the class active to the centered, focused image. 
The images  have a class of "item". I am using data-href because I need to have my images in a  rather than an  tag due to some constraints in contentflow  .
I have tried the following code:

HTML

```
   <div class="item"  title="Image" data-href="image.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto">
   <img  alt="image" src="thumb.jpg" /></div>
```

Script

```
$('#gallery').on('click', '.item:not(.active)', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
});

 $('.item[data-href]').each(function() { 
 $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href'));
  });

 $(".item").prettyPhoto();
```

No matter what, every image opens in the lightbox. I also tried this:

```
$('.item:not(.active)').off('click');
```

Since I'm still learning jQuery, if anyone can point me in the right direction, i would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$(".item").prettyPhoto();` why don't you just simply say `$(".active").prettyPhoto();` ?

Comment: If I do that then the prettyPhoto lightbox gallery will only show one  image, not all images, and the user will not have the option to scroll thru the prettyphoto gallery or have a slideshow within the lightbox.